# unable to load full view using cakePHP requestAction

Tags: php, cakephp, view, cakephp-1.3, helper

I have a question. I'm trying to use the [requestAction](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/991/requestAction) method of cakePHP to load a view file, but it doesn't seem to work. On their page we can read the following:

> You can use requestAction() to retrieve a fully rendered view by
>   passing 'return' in the  options: requestAction($url,
>   array('return'));

I tried doing that, but I still couldn't get the content of my .ctp view file. Is there anything that I'm missing?

By the way, I'm doing this inside of another view.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you paste your code that you are running?

Answer (score 1):

This function doesn't just load view files. It simulates a web browser accessing the URL and returns what ever the controller in question renders. The default behaviour is sending the result to output, if you use the return parameter you have to remember to print it yourself:

```
$this->requestAction("MyController/myaction/param");
```

is equivalent to

```
echo $this->requestAction("MyController/myaction/param", array("return"));
```

Comment: Joni, that will not work. It needs to be: $this->requestAction("Mycontroller/myaction/param", array( 'return' ) ); not 'return' => true. In the latter case, you are passing return as the array key, not the value.

Comment: Joni - I am curious to know where you learned that, this example is direct from the book: echo $this->requestAction(array('controller' => 'articles', 'action' => 'featured'), array('return')); - http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/991/requestAction

Comment: You are right, it should be `array("return")`. I remembered it wrong and didn't check.

Answer (score 0):

requestAction calls an action, not the associated view. If you want to call the associated view you need to do it like this:

```
echo $this->requestAction("Mycontroller/myaction/param", array( 'return' ) );
```

That will let cake know to render the associated view file.

Comment: If you find an answer helpful, please accept it. It will increase your chances of getting help in the future.